# JDBC connections from managed Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Looking for a way to JDBC from managed Cloud Run to a Cloud SQL instance that doesn't require opening up a public IP on the database.

Per the documentation, managed Cloud Run only supports UNIX socket access, which JDBC doesn't really support. I tried junixsockets (https://kohlschutter.github.io/junixsocket/dependency.html) and couldn't get it to work.

I'd prefer to not be reduced to having to run a SOCKS proxy :).

Comment: Cloud SQL Socket Factory provides similar features as Cloud SQL Proxy: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory

Answer (score 0):

There is now documentation on connecting Cloud SQL to Cloud Run via JDBC: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#connecting_to (click on the Java tab)